# VSTS - Build Definition - Multiple Agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In VSTS onlie, We have created a private pool and two agents are created (Say A, B). We want to create a build definition with two phases.

Is it possible to run first phase on Agent A and second phase on Agent B ?

Each phase, in agent selection it is showing `<inherit from definition>` instead of agents we have created to choose from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently the capability of different agents per phase is not yet available in VSTS. We are working on the ability to set different agents on the phases.

Comment: Hello. Is there a link to a uservoice or repo with progress or this as a feature request?

Answer (score 1):

Each agent has a list of capabilities which includes information about the agent, what OS it is installed on and different SDK's, frameworks and other software installed on the agent.  You can view the capabilities of an agent by selecting an agent in the Agent Pools page (found at the URL  https://{your_account}.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool) and opening the Capabilities tab.

In a build phase you can specify demands which will force the phase to run only on agents with the capabilities matching those demands.  For instance you could restrict a phase to run only on an agent with a specified Agent.ComputerName.  You can also manually add capabilities to agents and then specify them in the demands of a build phase.  Documentation for this can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options#demands.